# How to view built-in function from source code of mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**instr**, **concat**, **trim**... functions is built-in functions in mariadb. I see source code of mariadb on github at https://github.com/MariaDB/server.
How I can view the code that implement that function?

Comment: can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Not real familiar with MariaDB source, but I would suspect the implementations for these functions are in a similar location as MySQL. You might try adding the MySQL tag to your question to get more eyeballs.